# How can I improve the performance of my code? Selenium + JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, performance, selenium, arraylist

I am trying to write a script to test a website with selenium webdriver but I have a problem.
There is a table on the website. If I hover over a field, I get some informations about the field. The information is saved in a json-file. There is a lot of data in the json file(about 23000 json objects).
The file looks like this:

```
  {
    "origin": "13212",
    "destination": "15512",
    "time": 17,
    "days": "17",
    "people": "25"
  },
  {
    "origin": "34123",
    "destination": "15122",
    "time": 18,
    "days": "17",
    "people": "79"
  },
  {
    "origin": "13212",
    "destination": "15512",
    "time": 10,
    "days": "17",
    "people": "39"
  },  ...
```

I filled the data in 5 different arraylists with this method:

```java
public void fillArrays() {
        File file = new File(dirPath);
        try {
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.toURI())), "UTF-8");
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(content);
            Map<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                for (String key : obj.keySet()) {
                    switch (key) {
                    case "origin":
                        map.put(key, originList);
                        originList.add(obj.get(key));
                        break;
                    case "destination":
                        map.put(key, destinationList);
                        destinationList.add(obj.get(key));
                        break;
                    case "time":
                        map.put(key, timesList);
                        timesList.add(obj.get(key));
                        break;
                    case "days":
                        map.put(key, daysList);
                        daysList.add(obj.get(key));
                        break;
                    case "people":
                        map.put(key, peopleList);
                        peopleList.add(obj.get(key));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

To test the field of the table I used this code:

```java
for (int arrayChecker = 0; arrayChecker < originList.size(); arrayChecker++) {
    if (originList.get(arrayChecker).toString().equals(firstEle.getText())
            && destinationList.get(arrayChecker).toString().equals(lastEle.getText())) {
        totalPeople += Integer.parseInt(peopleList.get(arrayChecker).toString());
    }
}
numberAsString = numberFormat.format(totalPeople);
assertEquals(infoElement.getText(), "Information: Total time: " + numberAsString + " people");
```

The code works absolutely fine but is really really slow. To test a field of the table the code needs like 2 minutes.

Is there any way to improve the performance and make the tests faster?

Comment: Are you sure the slow implémentation Works? Is it normal to add the same lists to all key values?

Comment: I dont know what you mean, but im sure this code works for me. I want to give a example. In the Json-file there are for "origin: 13212" and "destination": "15512" for every time(0-23) an amount of people that traveled like you can see in the example above. In my code example I add every people with the "origin: 13212" and "destination": "15512" to get the total amount of people. Sometimes I need the time as condition too. And then the performance gets even slower.

Comment: Am i getting this wrong or are you adding the whole [people/days/time/etc] list in the map every time it loops through each loop, is this intended?
It seems counter productive to add the same list over and over with one element extra element each time it loops.